# label text moves up

Tags: c#, winforms

I have labels with texts in a panel. The labels have `AutoSize=true` and `AutoEllipsis=true`. Now if I resize the window so that part of the label is hidden - the text seem to move up a few pixels! (If I set `AutoSize=false` the problem disappears)

Anyone know why, or how to make sure the text stays put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `Anchor` properties of the Label to `none`.

This will keep the label text in middle.

Refer [Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx).

**OR**

Set the `MaximumSize` property to whatever figures you want to adjust with, so that it can not grow.

Comment: The labels are only anchored to left and right, and I would like them to stay that way. Is there no way to keep them anchored without the text jumping up?

Comment: when you change the pixels or monitor settings, it is aout to change the object settings on windows forms.